# How to install extensions on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I launched `vscode` (linux) on `raspberryPi3` at first and wanted to install `cpptool`.

So I　pressed:

```
Ctrl + Shift + p
```

and commanded

```
ext install cpptool
```

But then showed

> No Commnads Mathing

Additionally, I couldn't install all other extensions.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl + Shift + P` opens the command-palette, which can be used to run commands based on their "pretty name".

The easiest way to install extensions, is to first open the "Quick Open" interface (`Ctrl + P`), and then type `ext install <extension>`.

You can also install extensions directly from the command-palette, by opening it, and typing `Extensions: Install Extension`, and then selecting (or typing) the name of an extension.

It's worth noting that when you run the `Extensions: Install Extension` command in the command-palette, all it does is open the "Quick Open" interface, and then insert `ext install` into it.